# RuntimeError: (maximum recursion depth exceeded.) traceback object at 0x5c87d88 Odoo 7

Tags: reporting, openerp-7, accounts

When i want to print **Profit and Loss** from Account > Report > Legal Report > Profit and Loss, it generates an error in a small **openerp warning dialog box** "maximum recursion depth exceeded(type exceptions.RuntimeError>, RuntimeError (maximum recursion depth exceeded.) traceback object at 0x5c87d88>)"

"My aim was to print P & L report for last year 2015 with the following filters"

Fiscal Year = 2015, Filters by period = 11/2015 and 12/2015

I have check different forums there seems to be this kind of error but not in this kind of scenerio.

Note: Other legal report generates and work fine. My Odoo version is 7

I will appreciate someones help

Comment: Is this a programming question or an Oodo application support question?

Comment: odoo user's forum is here : https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1

Comment: Odoo application question

Comment: Has anyone been able to help solve the above openerp 7 problem